# How to concatenate XPath in scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I am struggling for quite some time now on this issue. This is the table from which I need to extract `Annual div` instead of `Annual Div yield`.

```
<table class="horizontalTable col1of3 lastCol">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="first">
      <th>Annual div <span class="sub">(TTM)</span></th>
      <td>5.49 <span class="currencyCode">GBX</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Annual div yield <span class="sub">(TTM)</span></th>
      <td>6.04%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Div ex-date</th>
      <td><span class="nowrap">Sep 25 2013</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="last">
      <th>Div pay-date</th>
      <td><span class="nowrap">Nov 22 2013</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I wrote this XPath query but it is bringing both `Annual div` and `Annual div yield`

```
Annual_div = sel.xpath('//table[contains(@class, "horizontalTable col1of3")]/tbody/tr[th[contains(.,"Annual div")]]').extract()
```

Result:

```
<tr class="first"><th>Annual div <span class="sub">(TTM)</span></th><td>5.49 <span class="currencyCode">GBX</span></td></tr>', u'<tr><th>Annual div yield <span class="sub">(TTM)</span></th><td>5.83%</td></tr>
```

When I write match on excact text then the result does not yield any result:

```
Annual_div = sel.xpath('//table[contains(@class, "horizontalTable col1of3")]/tbody/tr[th[text()="Annual div"]]').extract()
```

It seems it is to do with the span (TTM) I am not sure how to concatenate both Annual div (TTM) to come up with exact match.

Please help me.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare by an exact match you are missing a whitespace at the end. This should work:

```
//table[contains(@class, "horizontalTable col1of3")]/tbody/tr[th/text() = "Annual div "]]
```

However, if you want to remove leading and trailing spaces you can use `nornmalize-space()` like so:

```
//table[contains(@class, "horizontalTable col1of3")]/tbody/tr[normalize-space(th/text()) = 'Annual div']
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [XPath's `normalize-space()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space).

For example:

```
Annual_div = sel.xpath('//table[contains(@class, "horizontalTable col1of3")]/tbody/tr[normalize-space(th)="Annual div (TTM)"]').extract()
```

or:

```
Annual_div = sel.xpath('//table[contains(@class, "horizontalTable col1of3")]/tbody/tr[normalize-space(th/text())="Annual div"]')
```

Comment: Seems @dirkk and I were answering at the same time